# Using Javascript to download file in Wicket

Tags: ajax, file, wicket

I am confused on how to do this.. Currently I am implementing an automatic download using Javascript:

target.appendJavaScript("location.href='"+ "./Access.xls" + "';");

This doesn't work.. What is the proper way to trigger an automatic download and how do I properly set the url? I am not too familiar with Javascript but trying to implement this. The file is in the root of the project.. but it tells me it is not found.

Also, when the user downloads it, I would like to then delete it right away after it is downloaded using Javascript, how can I do this? I am using Javascript because I am calling this file within an ajax method.

Thanks!

Comment: For the first part, read up on Wicket's resource management: http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/resources.html To delete the file, I'm not sure what you mean. Delete on the server or the client?

Comment: Delete the file on server side. Also, thanks for the link. For more of a javascript question, I am confused on what to put for the URL inside the location.href... if the file is located in the root of the project   when I run the program locally.. how do I get its relative path so it can be accessed on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to get access to that resource, you should use a `ResourceReference` as explained [here](http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/resources.html). To get the url of a `ResourceReference` use:

```
RequestCycle#urlFor(ResourceReference, PageParameters)
```

However, I don't understand what you need regarding deletion of the file once downloaded. If your file is contained in the jar/war of your project, I don't believe it can be deleted from inside the web app. You could block access to it once it's downloaded however, if that makes sense. Not sure what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Thanks Bernie, that helped get me in the right direction.